# Meteor - Filter collection items published by dates

Tags: date, meteor, collections

I am currently trying to filter a meteor collection based on two parameters they are: currentDate and coming from the collection dateEventEnds.

This is my current publish code:

```
Meteor.publish('recursos', function() {
  let today = Date.now();
  return Recursos.find({ 'recursos.fechaEnd': { $gt: today }});
});
```

Which is effectively not doing anything. I think this is due to:

- Date.now() producing the date in milliseconds. Ex: 1463058648464
- While recursos.fechaEnd has it stored like this: "2016-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"

Have also tried using: new Date(), but still nothing happens:

```
Meteor.publish('recursos', function() {
  let today = new Date();
  return Recursos.find({ 'recursos.fechaEnd': { $gt: today }});
});
```

- new Date() results are like this: Thu May 12 2016 09:50:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

So it looks like the issue revolves around the way dates are presented. How could I change them to both use the same date format? Is it by changing them to Milliseconds?

The template where I need to do the filtering is suscribe to both the collection and an EasySearchIndex which looks like this:

```
RecursosIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: Recursos,
    fields: ['clase', 'direccion.city'],
    engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB({
      sort: () => ['fechaStart']
    })
});
```

Should the filtering happen here?

Thanks

Comment: just guessing: `let today = new Date();` ?

Comment: Have tried that as well, used Date.now() as it produces the current date.

Comment: @Julien looks like the issue has to do more with how the date values are stored/represented

Comment: new Date() also produces the current date, and Date comparison is supposed to work with Date objects. Also, another thing, you're looking for objects with a date in the future (later than now), is that what you want ?

Comment: @julien I am using EasySearch, and noticed that the template was suscribe to both the collection and the collectionIndex. I have ammended my question to include the EasySearch index. Maybe hte filter needs to be done here?

Comment: `$gt: today` means you want documents from the future, doc.

Comment: In addition to aedm comment, did you try to set the `recursos.fechaEnd` with `new Date().getTime()` (at the moment you add it) ? In order to have the same unit when you do the comparison.

Comment: @aedm yeah perhaps that's what he wants but it could also be the cause of the problem

Comment: So i tried newDate().getTime() but looking at how collections2 is storing the field in the DB it seems the it is not using ISODate and thus the comparison doesn't happen.

Comment: @smeloa That is the point no ? `new Date().getTime()` return a number, if you store it in `recursos.fechaEnd` you just have to compare it with a new date in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is perfectly fine, Mongo is quite capable of searching and sorting by date fields. The problem is that your dates in Mongo are stored as strings and not as actual dates. If you look at an object you should see fields like:

A real date:

```
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-09-18T05:42:50.105Z")
```

A string:

```
"createdAt" : "2015-09-18T05:42:50.105Z"
```

To *upgrade* your existing dataset from strings to dates, run the following:

```
Recursos.find().forEach(function(r){
  Recursos.update(r._id,{$set: { 'recursos.fechaEnd': new Date(r.fechaEnd) }});
});
```

Of course you can convert more than one date at a time, I suspect your object also has a `fechaStart`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks like I was looking at the info on MeteorToys, but Robomongo does show it properly. The real issue then lies with the template being linked to EasySearch and needing the filter there...